# C++ logical error: pointer array & user-defined class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Below are 2 pieces of programs from the "Intro to C++" by MIT Open Courseware, problem 2.5 and 2.6 of assignment 3.

Both are supposed to have logical errors. However I couldn't spot any even by using a computer. There weren't any errors generated, the results also looked normal.

Anyone could spot anything abnormal in them?

This is problem 2.6:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point{
    private:
    int x,y;

    public:
    Point(int u, int v) : x(u), y(v){}
    int getX() {return x;}
    int getY() {return y;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Point *p = new Point(5,3);
    cout<<p->getX()<<' '<<p->getY()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is problem 2.5:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int* nums = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cin >> nums[i];
        cout << nums[i];
    }

    delete nums;
}
```

Comment: If you couldn't find anything wrong, you sure didn't try very hard when testing this (at least the second one).

Answer (score 2):

The problem 2.6 misses 'delete p;'. The problem 2.5 should have 'delete []num;' instead of 'delete num;'. Both problems introduce a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I see the following problems:

1. Memory is not freed. "delete p;" should be called at the end
2. Incorrect variant of "delete" is called. You should use "delete[] nums;" to free memory allocated for arrays.